# Bug report and Settings crash on Nexus 4

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, settings, crashes, bug-report-feature

My Nexus 4 is rooted with stock ROM (version 4.4.4) and custom recovery TWRP. Recently it automatically generated some bug report: one is a png image (just a blank screen in black) and another text file in 9MB. Since it's a huge file, what should I look for in the text file?

Also, there is another problem with my Nexus 4: Settings keeps crashing when an app is selected under Settings/Apps with error message: "Unfortunately, Settings has stopped." It's described in details [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-4/help/help-settings-crashing-logcat-t2855603). I'm not so sure if the two problems are related. I've tried to re-flash the factory image of 4.4.4, but the problem remains.

Comment: Why would you be looking for something in the bug report file? Are you an Android OS developer?

Comment: I thought that the bug report might reveal something about any potential problems including the Settings crash. Any suggestion regarding the Settings crash issue?

Comment: Did you wipe the data and cache when flashing? What ROM were you coming from before you flashed KitKat 4.4.4?

Comment: Yes I wiped data and cache in TWRP after flashing. It was KitKat 4.4.3 before the recent flashing.

Comment: I've been using stock ROM all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about the Settings issue, but the bug report thing is pretty popular: Google's devices do a report now and then (don't ask me why.... maybe those reports are sent to Google to keep everything under control or to check if something goes wrong), so just don't worry.

On my Nexus 5, I can even make a bug report every time I want (just by pressing power + volume up at the same time) and you should have the same feature. It basically depends on the activation of USB Debugging: if it's active, then the bug report creation is active. You can disable it by simply disabling USB Debugging or by going into `/system/bin` and renaming `bugmailer.sh` to `bugmailer.sh.bak` or deleting it. Then just reboot and no more bugmailer.

P.S.: for the Settings issue, just try the simplest thing: go into the app drawer -> long-press on the "Settings" app -> move it to the upper side (App Info) -> clear data.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I really appreciate it. I thought that the bug report might provide some clues about the problems I'm having. Since it's a text file, someone with enough knowledge may be able to parse through and find some clues. In addition to the Settings crash, the time and location stuff is not working properly either on my Nexus 4. I also tried your suggestion of long pressing on "Settings". However, that basically brings up the same error: "Unfortunately, Settings has stopped."